# Magento 1.4.2 + APC: Clearing cache has no effect on changing settings

Tags: magento, apc

We got a server with Magento 1.4.2 CE, APC 3.1.9 is installed and Magento is configured to use it as backend cache.

We experienced a weird behaviour with caching. Every change we make in the backend is not displayed until apache2 was restarted/APC opcode cache has been cleared. This includes e.g. changing the Welcome Message or activating/deactivating Google Analytics.

**The question:** Why does APC cache full pages? We do not want this behaviour and it seems not to be standard. For every little change in the backend, we need to clear the opcode cache. Clearing the Magento Cache does not help.

For completeness, here is our `/etc/php5/conf.d/apc.ini`:

```
extension=/usr/lib/php5/20090626/apc.so
apc.enabled=1
apc.file_update_protection=2
apc.optimization=0
apc.shm_size=128M
apc.include_once_override=0
apc.shm_segments=1
apc.gc_ttl=7200
apc.ttl=7200
apc.num_files_hint=1024
apc.enable_cli=0
```

Enabling/Disabling Google Analytics will also have no effect after the 7200s TTL. Maybe because our cache doesn't run full at this time. 40% of its capacity is used with about 98% hit rate.

This is the full settings output from apc.php:

```
apc.cache_by_default    1
apc.canonicalize        1
apc.coredump_unmap      0
apc.enable_cli      0
apc.enabled         1
apc.file_md5        0
apc.file_update_protection  2
apc.filters 
apc.gc_ttl          7200
apc.include_once_override   0
apc.lazy_classes        0
apc.lazy_functions      0
apc.max_file_size       1M
apc.mmap_file_mask  
apc.num_files_hint      1024
apc.preload_path    
apc.report_autofilter   0
apc.rfc1867         0
apc.rfc1867_freq        0
apc.rfc1867_name        APC_UPLOAD_PROGRESS
apc.rfc1867_prefix      upload_
apc.rfc1867_ttl     3600
apc.serializer      default
apc.shm_segments        1
apc.shm_size        128M
apc.slam_defense        1
apc.stat            1
apc.stat_ctime      0
apc.ttl         7200
apc.use_request_time    1
apc.user_entries_hint   4096
apc.user_ttl        0
apc.write_lock      1
```

Comment: I got the hint to disable Magento backend cache, as it has fewer impact on performance than APC opcode caching itself.
Deactivating the cache in local.xml and clearing var/cache really helped. The stores are nearly as fast as before, but the bug that I had to clear the opcode cache every time I changed a single setting is gone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

APC keeps both a terminal and web based cache. Since you can only clear the "web" cached hits from a web based URL call and not the command line, This is why after restarting apache clears the **APC Web based cache**. You'll most likely want to setup a script to clear the cache with a script similar so you can simply call it from the CLI or script.

```
echo "Clearing APC web cache\n";
system('wget --spider --quiet http://localhost/clear_apc_cache.php');

echo "Clearing APC command line user cache\n";
apc_clear_cache('user');

echo "Clearing APC command line opcode cache\n";
apc_clear_cache();
```

Obviously you'll need to create the `clear_apc_cache.php` corresponding file with the same two APC internal method calls within it, `apc_clear_cache();` and `apc_clear_cache('user');`

Also, I'd setup a local area to view the APC cache as well:

http://www.electrictoolbox.com/apc-php-cache-information/

Comment: Well, this isn't about fixing Magento's weird behaviour, however it is great to not having to restart the webserver everytime. So this is accepted. Btw. we already have the cache information running, see reference to apc.php in the text.

Answer (score 0):

You can also Set apc.stat to zero. (apc.stat=0) in your PHP.ini file.

If it is set to 1 it does not look for file updates, which gives better performance but requires an apache restart after an update. Setting to 0 it will check for file updates and add them to the cache (ie. your updates will be visible on the site).

Comment: I'm sorry to tell you that this is wrong. It works exactly opposite. apc.stat = 1 will let APC check for changed files, while apc.stat = 0 disables the check for changed files. The setting chosen in the config in the question is ok. See [php manual](http://www.php.net/manual/de/apc.configuration.php#ini.apc.stat)